# Android library for small 2D game

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm relatively new to Android (about 1 year experience on standard apps), and I have a great idea for a small 2D Game.

My question is : Should I code it in native code only (using `shapes`, `listeners`, `backgrounds`, or some components I don't even know) or is there  a `library` to use that will ease the development and/or improve user experience ?

This game will not be an advanced 2D game, but more "CandyCrush-like" little games.

If you come up with some nice libraries or SDK to use, please note that portability to other platforms is very important.

Thanks!

Comment: please use library, it will save you hours of work. try libgdx, it seems best documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest to use a game engine, even for a simple game such as a CandyCrush-like.

It will save you a lot of effort for basic things which are common to all games and quite long to properly implement (such as game loop management, sprite animations,...). Most of them are based on OpenGL ES  which is quite a nightmare to program manually but provides great performance.

Then you should decide which language you're most familiar with (C++, Java, Javascript, Lua, Ruby, whatever...): it will improve your learning curve.

Choosing a cross-platform game engine might also be a good idea (porting a native game is a huge work).

Take a look at those:

- [cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/) (C++)
- [corona SDK](http://coronalabs.com/products/corona-sdk/)
- [Unity](http://unity3d.com/unity)
- ...

Note that this discussion would be more relevant on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ (and you might get better answers too).

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely look at all these game engines. I underestimated the fact that porting native code could be a nightmare, and now that you pointed it out, it seems obvious! Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is an old answer, but are you aware of any game engines that support Ruby and are cross-platform (Android and iOS)?

Comment: @mydoghasworms https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/game_libraries

Answer (score 0):

If your game is really simple, you can try developing with either

- **Android Canvas** or
- **OpenGL ES**

Especially for developers that are not that experienced, who want to develop simple games, the Canvas is a good option in combination with a `SurfaceView`. Alternatively, I can recommend this engine:

**[AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/)**

or

**[Unity Engine](http://unity3d.com/unity/multiplatform/mobile)** with 2D extension could also be a good option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! Please note that your second link is pointing to AndEngine website.

Comment: Sorry about that, that must be my reocurring copy-paste issue :) - I changed it.